# Excel VBA looping block of code until cell has no value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a block of VBA code that does exactly what I need it to do (searches a customer account in a HTML based program and pulls data to a spreadsheet) but I'd like to have the whole block of code loop and pull the same data for multiple accounts based on a column of account numbers. I've tried a few different types of loops but can't seem to get the loop to work with the rowData variable. It seems so simple (and I'm sure it is) but I just can't see it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here's the part of the block (with comments) I'd like to loop...

```
rowData = 6 'set it to the first row of player account data
dblTotalS = 0
dblTotalT = 0

'START LOOP HERE using rowData variable to check if column is empty 

' Input the account number & click search
IE.document.getElementById("accountNumber").Value = Me.Cells(rowData, 6).Value 'use the rowdata variable to get which row we are at
IE.document.getElementById("action").Click
If Not IEWait(IE) Then
    GoTo EndMe
End If

' navigate to the activity page
IE.navigate my_url3
If Not IEWait(IE) Then
    GoTo EndMe
End If

' input search criteria
IE.document.getElementById("site").Value = Me.Cells(7, 4).Value
IE.document.getElementById("action").Click
If Not IEWait(IE) Then
    GoTo EndMe
End If

dblCustomerTTotal = 0
dblCustomerSTotal = 0
For i = 1 To 1
    Set TDelements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr") 
    For Each TDelement In TDelements
        If TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsCustomerTContent" Then
            dblCustomerTTotal = dblCustomerTTotal + VBA.CDbl(TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText)
        ElseIf TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsCustomerSContent" Then
            dblCustomerSTotal = dblCustomerSTotal + VBA.CDbl(TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText)
        End If
    Next
    Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems
        If e.Value = "Next Results" Then
            e.Click
            If Not IEWait(IE) Then
                GoTo EndMe
            End If
            i = 0
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
Next i
Me.Cells(rowData, 7).Value = dblCustomerTTotal
Me.Cells(rowData, 8).Value = dblCustomerSTotal
Me.Cells(rowData, 9).Value = dblCustomerTTotal + dblCustomerSTotal
dblTotalT = dblTotalT + dblCustomerTTotal
dblTotalS = dblTotalS + dblCustomerSTotal
'
' END LOOP HERE

EndMe:
IE.Quit
On Error GoTo 0 'reset the error handler
End Sub
```

Again, this seems so simple but every loop I've tried just doesn't seem to work for me...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop. Assuming the account numbers are in column 6:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = Cells(10000, 6).End(xlUp).Row

rowData = 6 'set it to the first row of player account data
dblTotalS = 0
dblTotalT = 0

'START LOOP HERE using rowData variable to check if column is empty
For x = rowData To lastRow

    ' Input the account number & click search
    IE.document.getElementById("accountNumber").Value = Me.Cells(x, 6).Value 'use the rowdata variable to get which row we are at
    IE.document.getElementById("action").Click
    If Not IEWait(IE) Then
        GoTo EndMe
    End If

    ' navigate to the activity page
    IE.navigate my_url3
    If Not IEWait(IE) Then
        GoTo EndMe
    End If

    ' input search criteria
    IE.document.getElementById("site").Value = Me.Cells(7, 4).Value
    IE.document.getElementById("action").Click
    If Not IEWait(IE) Then
        GoTo EndMe
    End If

    dblCustomerTTotal = 0
    dblCustomerSTotal = 0
    For i = 1 To 1
        Set TDelements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each TDelement In TDelements
            If TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsCustomerTContent" Then
                dblCustomerTTotal = dblCustomerTTotal + VBA.CDbl(TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText)
            ElseIf TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsCustomerSContent" Then
                dblCustomerSTotal = dblCustomerSTotal + VBA.CDbl(TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText)
            End If
        Next
        Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each e In elems
            If e.Value = "Next Results" Then
                e.Click
                If Not IEWait(IE) Then
                    GoTo EndMe
                End If
                i = 0
                Exit For
            End If
        Next e
    Next i
    Me.Cells(rowData, 7).Value = dblCustomerTTotal
    Me.Cells(rowData, 8).Value = dblCustomerSTotal
    Me.Cells(rowData, 9).Value = dblCustomerTTotal + dblCustomerSTotal
    dblTotalT = dblTotalT + dblCustomerTTotal
    dblTotalS = dblTotalS + dblCustomerSTotal
    '
    ' END LOOP HERE
Next x

EndMe:
IE.Quit
On Error GoTo 0 'reset the error handler

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked great, had to change the placement of the code a bit but worked like a charm. The only issue I have now is that when it imports the data (the "Me.Cells(rowdata..." lines) it just overwrites the data each time. Is there a short/quick way to make it move down a row with each set of data or to even align the data with the account number? Sorry, again this seems simple but I can't see a way to do it without having to set up more variables to account for moving through the rows each time it loops. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry didnt see the last bit. You're now using the variable x in place of rowData - each time the loop iterates x is increased by one. So replace rowData with x e.g. Me.Cells(rowData, 7).Value = dblCustomerTTotal becomes Me.Cells(x, 7).Value = dblCustomerTTotal

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for the help @Absinthe